Upgrading python in MySQL Workbench
The python version in MySQL Workbench keeps getting flagged my our security because it is not the most up to date version. I have the most up to date version on my PC, but inside the MySQL files it appears to be the old version. How can i update so that it is the same version as my PC?
Tried seeing if it was possible to update python, but no luck

add some detail/content - version(s) of the various components involved  ... workbench, python , OS , etc . Have you read/researched the Workbench documentation wrt configuring the environment ?

Having kind the same question regarding mysql workbench 8.0.38
Our security says this file must be updated:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\python.exe (3.12.2.0)

I have just updated python.exe (downloaded newest version of it) whats seems to work but can't guarantee anything...

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
